# Can I open a port on the docker container in “overlay” network to communicate with the server on the local host?

Tags: docker, docker-swarm, docker-network

I have a container running with -network= my-overlay-network, that I can prevent any api calls within the containers to the service on the internet. However, I do need to make an api calls within the container to the localhost.

I used the -p dockerport:localhostport in the docker run command to publish/map the port of the container to the localhost. However, it always shows as "Connection refused".

Also I tried to add --add-host host.docker.internal:$(ip addr show docker0 | grep -Po 'inet \K[\d.]+') in docker run. I still cannot connect the server on the port. I have got "Couldn't connect to server" to host.docerk.internal:port.

Can I open a port when the container is under the overlay network?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you got the ports backwards, instead of `-p dockerport:localhostport` it should be `-p localhostport:containerport`, where `localhostport` is the port you want to open on the local host, and `containerport` is the port the container exposed in it's `dockerfile`.